# I can't deploy nextjs 13 app using firestore to firebase

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting

I can't deploy nextjs app that uses firestore but when I try to depoly it with fire base I get this:
[image]

When I was setting it up I did this :

```
- firebase init 
- then select the Hosting
- What do you want to use as your public directory? app
- Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? No
- npm run build
- firebase deploy
```

I tried everything please help me

Comment: Looks like you didn't replace the index.html content in the public folder that gets deployed by default.

Comment: I tried it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable the web frameworks setting first. See the steps below if you wish to integrate Next.js with Firebase:

1. **Update the Firebase Tools CLI version**: run command `npm install -g firebase-tools`
2. **Create a new workspace or directory**: `firebase-nextjs-app`
3. **Enable web frameworks settings**: run command `firebase experiments:enable webframeworks`
4. **Initialize Firebase**: `firebase init hosting`
5. **Select a Firebase project**: input or select a valid project ID
6. **Do you want to use a web framework**? select Yes
7. **What folder would you like to use for your web application's root directory**: input your application's root directory or use hosting by default. In this step, Firebase CLI will try to determine if there's an existing framework used by the project - proceed to step 8 if there's none
8. **Please choose the framework**: select Next.js
   9 **What language would you like to use**: choose JavaScript or TypeScript
9. Wait until Firebase CLI completed the creation of Next.js app
10. **In which region would you like to host server-side content, if applicable**: select a region from the list
11. **Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub**: No
12. **Deploy your app**: `firebase deploy`

Comment: Its the same.I don't know what to do

Comment: Please add your firebase.json file here.